# BIRT Filter by Parameters Return a Blank Report When it Shouldn't

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

let me further elaborate on my concern:

I am working on some test reports on BIRT to be familiarized with it and came across an unsettling problem.

I created a data source that connects to a test SQL Server database, a data source that will return building, floor, room, and the number of employees that contain more than one employee, and two String parameters that lets the user choose the building and floor so the report filters by just that one.

The problem happens when I test it with a building and floor that I know are in the result set. For some reason the report filters a blank result, as if the building and floors are not present in the data set result.

I tried filtering by just the building first and then the floor but the same thing happens. If I take out the filter then the report shows up without a problem.

Why does this happen? I am assuming it's the way I input the parameters, but I am not sure.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Julio, can you please provide a screen short of your data set query? Also a screen shot of the input parameters set on the data set?

Comment: Hello @Neo, thank you for your response. I got this to work after some tinkering with the data source. But I didn't want to leave you in the dark: I followed [this example](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Frp-EnablingTheUserToFilterData.html) to the letter and the report failed to show up. I ended up removing the filter from the data set and the table that displayed it and it worked as expected. Thank you once again!